# Parsing input files within python script

Tags: python, bash

I have written a bash script which:

1. Loops on some dcd files within the working directory
2. Creates a python script, which post-process of those files and
3. Saves some results for each file

```bash
for dcd in ${workdir}/*.dcd; do
dcd_name2="$(basename "$dcd")"
dcd_name="${dcd_name2/.dcd/}"
# print a python script
printf " # 1-load dcd file
dcd = parseDCD('${dcd}')
# 2- do something with the dcd file
dcd.superpose() lala
# 3- Plotting results

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
showFractVars(md_ensemble) 
plt.savefig( 'results_${dcd_name}.png' ) > ./my_python_script.py
python ./my_python_script.py
done
```

Now I need to modify my algorithm to load all of the DCD files within the one script in the loop manner e.g. for 10 dcd files the python script should look like this

```python
dcd1 = parseDCD('${dcd1}')
dcd2 = parseDCD('${dcd2}')
dcd3 = parseDCD('${dcd3}')
# 2- do something with the dcd file
dcd1.superpose() lala
dcd2.superpose() lala
dcd3.superpose() lala
# 3- Plotting results

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
showFractVars(dcd1, dcd2,dcd3) 
plt.savefig( 'results_${dcd_name}.png' )
```

How should the "for loop" within of my first bash script should be modified to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the bash script is not need.

My suggestion is that you should use the `glob` python module and write a single python script that does all of the logic you wish for a given working directory

Here is an example script I've written, this is the best way you could probably handle this problem:

```python
# Imports
import argparse
import os
from glob import glob

# Third party imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
RESULT_NAME_TEPLATE = 'results_{file_name}.png'

def parse_dcd():

    # Your logic...
    pass

def handle_dcd_file(file_name):
    dcd = parse_dcd('${dcd}')

    # 2- do something with the dcd file
    dcd.superpose() 
    # 3- Plotting results

    plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
    showFractVars(md_ensemble)
    plt.savefig(RESULT_NAME_TEPLATE.format(file_name=file_name))    

def main(input_directory):

    dcd_files = glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.dcd'))

    for file_name in dcd_files:
        print "Handling {file_name}".format(file_name=file_name)
        handle_dcd_file(file_name)

    print "Finished handling {} dcd files from '{}'".format(len(dcd_files), os.path.abspath(input_directory))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Your program description")
    parser.add_argument('input_directory', nargs='?', default='.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not os.path.isdir(args.input_directory):
        parser.error("The input directory at '{}' does not exist!".format(args.input_directory))
    main(args.input_directory)
```

Example usage:
the script accepts an optional `input_directory` command line argument. If none is supplied the current directory is assumed:

Current directory
`python dcd_parser.py`

Given a directory
`python dcd_parser.py /home/user/example/dir`